# silverlight 4 datagrid: how to put custom message instead of "Error" in validation panel

Tags: validation, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

So, in datagrid or dataform if there are validation errors we have white Error word upon red ribbon.

How do I put my message there?

**EDIT:** Clarification: I'm happy with everything. The only thing I want is to translate "ERROR" word displayed in datagrid validation panel into other language.

Answer (score 1):

Because Silverlight is big on separation of concerns this really should be driven by validation in your middle tier using Data Annotation Validators and the INotifyDataErrorInfo.  A good approach is to rely on WCF RIA Services and what it provides.  See this article: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-6-Validating-Data.aspx

You could create your own error control to display the errors as well, but the pattern of putting business rules enforcement purely at the client is not ideal.  WCF RIA Services allows business rules coded at the middle tier to flow effortlessly into the client side code.  One problem with grids however is the fact that you are never really editing more than one row at a time so display multirow errors is not possible.

Comment: Okay, the SDK datagrid does not normall expose this so you'll need to extend the datagrid and expose the validation summary as seen here http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/166036/374078.aspx.  Once you do that you should be able to use converters or even code to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I managed to do this by adding this to my custom styles resource dictionary:

'
Style TargetType="dataInput:ValidationSummary">

```
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="#FFDC020D" CornerRadius="2" x:Name="Header" Margin="-1,-1,-1,0">
                    <StackPanel Margin="6,2,6,4" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid Height="13" Width="13">
                            <Ellipse Margin="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.505,0.65" EndPoint="0.5,0.058">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFCA000C" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9298" Offset="0.991"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Stroke>
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFDC8C8" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Path Fill="#DDD43940" Data="M5.5,2.5 L7.5,2.5 L7.5,8 L5.5,8 M5.5,9.5 L7.5,9.5 L7.5,10.5 L5.5,10.5"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Padding="4,1,0,0" Text="CUSTOM MESSAGE" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

where dataInput is 

`xmlns:dataInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"`

these styles and templates are really lengthy

Comment: Great work Ren.  It certainly is lengthy, but it does show how adaptive the SL/WPF UI architecure can be.  I just wish that common requirements such as you allowed for easier solutions; your problem is far from a corner case requirement.